# Wp-Cron cpanel job crashing website - how to debug

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have wp-cron.php disabled and then set as a cron job via cpanel. The site keeps going down and this always coincides with an email saying the cron job was killed by cpanel, so my working assumption is that the cron is eating resources and taking the site down.
There's nothing in the error log and the cron job always returns a blank page load.
Does anyone know how to turn on WP debug exclusively for the cron job or another way to debug what is causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked wether `error logging` is actually working?

Comment: if you tell us about the cron job which you set, then we can suggests some thing, if your cron job occupy all resource then it will happen, you can on the debug from config file

Comment: Thanks for the replies - error logging is working as it picks up some errors from other areas of the site.

Sorry Shakeel, I'm not sure I follow your question